# Storing a worksheet in an array and working on it

Tags: excel, vba

The below code deletes rows which do not match my criteria. It takes around 52 minutes as my rows exceed 1,68,000 and this will keep increasing.

I was using filters to reduce the data. That isn't an option any more. I have to delete rows based on my date compare range. It seems an array is my last resort, but I do not know how to store my worksheets in an array and work on them.

How do I store my worksheet in an array and work on it?

```
' to delete data not meeting criteria
Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
n1 = Range("n1")
n2 = Range("n2")
Worksheets("Temp Calc").Activate
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For z = lastrow To 2 Step -1
     If Cells(z, 6).Value = "CNF" Or Cells(z, 4).Value <= n1 Or Cells(z,3).Value >= n2 Then
          Rows(z).Delete
     End If
Next z
```

This is something basic.

```
Dim arr1(),  dim arr2() as variant
lastrow  = cells(Rows.count,1).End(XlUp).Row
lastcol = cells(1,column.count).End(xlRight).Column
arr1(lastrow,lastcol) <- I dont know if this is correct. 
<------How do I copy/paste my data into the array? ----->

<This is what I came up with for deleting what I dont need.>
For x=lastrow to 2 Step -1
If arr1(x,6)<>"" or arr1(x,6)<>"CNF" And arr(x,4)>=n1 And arr(x,3)<=n2 then
For k = lastrow to 2 
<I dont know how to delete rows in an array.
rows(x).delete ?
```

Comment: If you want the array approach then we can do that but what problems did you find with Autofilter?

Comment: filter was awesome but when my delete criteria was only blank cells and "CNF" but now i have to delete data based on dates.it does not filter my date ranges

Comment: May I see a sample data? just couple of rows... you can create a sample file and upload it in wikisend.com and share the link here. We will try the Autofilter approach first and then move on to Arrays if it doesn't work

Comment: ok siddharth,
[URL=http://wikisend.com/download/301436/Dashboard_for_Roshan.xlsm]Dashboard_for_Roshan.xlsm[/URL]
temp calc is my sheet
please ignore the codes they are outdated

Comment: Gr8. now gimme your exact filter criteria, dates/"Cnf" etc...

Comment: First i want to delete rows in cole 6 that have "" 
also i am storing two dates in variables n1 and n2 
now if col 4 > n1 And col 3 < n2 Then delete
please ignore CNF condition as some of my data has some exceptions to this which i want to keep

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32923/discussion-between-mathew-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: hey sid, the code does not finish the job.
for example my date is from 1/10/2013 to 31/10/2013
but after running the code i still have data from 2012 on it .

Comment: i have narrowed the problem down to fixing dates in n1 and n2 
i have tried two approaches one is selecting the dashboard sheet and then assigning range n1 and n2 values to n1 and n2 respectively.

second method was to using a worksheet("").cells().value function

both work but during execution of the code in various places it returns an error.and the execution time is increased. any ideas why this does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok further to our chat discussions, here is my autofilter approach.

**Your Requirement**

> First i want to delete rows in cole 6 that have ""
>   also i am storing two dates in variables n1 and n2
>   now if col 4 > n1 And col 3 < n2 Then delete
>   please ignore CNF condition as some of my data has some exceptions to this which i want to keep

Let's say your data looks like this

[image]

Now let's say `N1 = 5/1/2012` and `N2 = 7/1/2012`

If you visually see the screenshot then you will notice that there is only one row which meets the condition and that is Row 9 (Employee 623***).

**Code**

I have commented the code so that you will not have a problem understanding it.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FltrRng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim N1 As Date, N2 As Date

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp Calc")

    '~~> Start Date and End Date
    N1 = #5/1/2012#: N2 = #7/1/2012#

    With ws

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Get the last row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Identify your data range
        Set FltrRng = .Range("A1:F" & lRow)

        '~~> Filter the data as per your criteria
        With FltrRng
            '~~> First filter on blanks
            .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="="
            '~~> Next filter on Start Date
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">" & N1, Operator:=xlAnd
            '~~> Finally filter on End Date
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<" & N2, Operator:=xlAnd
            '
            '~~> And so on if required
            '

            '~~> Delete the filtered rows
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**After Screenshot**

If you notice that the required record has been deleted.

[image]

Comment: hello sid, this is not working for some reason my blank cells and the data that should be filtered out according to the date is still left.
debugging shows that the data being filtered

Comment: hello sid i can't figure out why it does not work
also please lend your help out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487806/reduce-for-loop-execution-time-that-returns-a-count

Comment: @mathew: Sorry was out... A pretty busy day! Are you still facing a problem with this question?

Comment: @Philip: Thanks but why the "?" :)

Comment: yea dude i have no idea whats wrong
give me 5 min im having dinner :)

Comment: done. i tried debugging it i see the filter being applied but the data does not get deleted

Comment: Post Chat, the problem is now sorted

Answer (score 3):

Try This :

```
         Dim varArrdata   as variant
         Dim lngloop      as long
         Dim strRows      as string
         vararrdata = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp)) ' OR use Range("A1").CurrentRegion
         For lngLoop = LBound(vararrdata) To UBound(vararrdata)
            If vararrdata(lngLoop, 6) = "CNF" Or vararrdata(lngLoop, 4) <= [n1] Or vararrdata(lngLoop, 3) >= [n2] Then
                strRows = strRows & "|" & lngLoop
            End If
         Next
         vararrdata = Split(Mid(strRows, 2), "|")
         Range("A" & Join(vararrdata, ",A")).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: hello mechanic 
ty for your suggestions ill try it out soon :)

Comment: your code uses a loop, which is the problem i am facing. it takes too much time

Comment: Yes ,It uses a loop but it loops in an array that takes less time in comarison to range..Did u try it?

Comment: i am getting a subscript out of range error on the if condition

Comment: Ohhh.....i made a mistake...range has not been made properly .. change this line: vararrdata = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp))

Comment: use this line in place of that If varArrdata(lngloop, 6) = "CNF" Or varArrdata(lngloop, 4) <= 1 Or varArrdata(lngloop, 3) >= 2 Then i just used ur code and tried to modified that so forgot to remove .value after each value of array :) and yes add ur lines also that you use to initialize n1 and n2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32931/discussion-between-mathew-and-mechanic)