# Find Value on other sheet and copy entire row

Tags: excel, vba

**Hello. I'm working on one project and I need some help. I'm not familiar with VBA so any your help will be very helpfull.

Here is What I want to do:

On sheet2, in cell A1 I write some value and when I click on the button and it have to start searching for this value on sheet1's Column D than if it will find this value, it will copy entire row(s) in 3rd row on sheet2

I found this code and it is working fine but I need to edit it for me.

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub SearchForString()

    Dim LSearchRow As Integer
    Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    'Start search in row 4
    LSearchRow = 4

    'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
    LCopyToRow = 2

    While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

        'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
        If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "D1" Then

            'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
            Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
            Selection.Copy

            'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'Move counter to next row
            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

            'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select

        End If

        LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

    Wend

    'Position on cell A3
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A3").Select

    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Comment: Why loop? Why not use autofilter and copy it in one go? See this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480975/storing-a-worksheet-in-an-array-and-working-on-them) Where the filtered rows are deleted. Instead of deleting it simply copy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put out another way to get what you want done, in a faster more reliable way. The following code uses built in Excel function, instead of VBA loops.

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim rngLastCell As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim lnglastrow1 As Long
Dim lnglastcolumn1 As Long



Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

lnglastrow1 = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' Replace "A" With column that has the most Rows
lnglastcolumn1 = sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set rngLastCell = sh.Cells(lnglastrow1 , lnglastcolumn1 )

With sh.Range("A1", rngLastCell)

'Replace the number in the field section with your Columns number
    .AutoFilter , _
        Field:=4, _
        Criteria1:=sh2.Range("A1").Value

    .Copy sh2.Range("A3")

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it is writing error: Runtime error 91 Object variable or With Block variable is not set and it is debugging on this: rngLastCell = sh.Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)

Comment: @SergiKhizanishvili Sorry, Forgot to add the Set command to the beginning of the line, should be fine now. updated my code.

Comment: @SergiKhizanishvili Sure thing, If you feel this fully satisfies the needs of the question remember to Accept, this answer as the correct answer. Click the check mark under the arrows next to my answer.

Comment: is there any chance to make this one like Criteria1:=sh2.Range("A1").Value range contains A1 value?

Comment: @SergiKhizanishvili Give this a shot `Criteria1:="=*"& sh2.Range("A1").Value & "*"`

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a corrected version of your code performing the requested actions:

```
Sub SearchForString()

    Dim LCopyToRow As Integer


    On Error GoTo Err_Execute


    'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
    LCopyToRow = 2

    Dim sheetTarget As String: sheetTarget = "sheet2"
    Dim sheetToSearch As String: sheetToSearch = "sheet1"
    Dim targetValue As String: targetValue = Sheets(sheetTarget).Range("A1").Value  'Value in sheet2!A1 to be searched in sheet1
    Dim columnToSearch As String: columnToSearch = "D"
    Dim iniRowToSearch As Integer: iniRowToSearch = 4
    Dim LSearchRow As Long 'As far as it is not clear the number of rows you will be considering, better relying on the long type
    Dim maxRowToSearch As Long: maxRowToSearch = 2000 'There are lots of rows, so better setting a max. limit

    If (Not IsEmpty(targetValue)) Then
        For LSearchRow = iniRowToSearch To Sheets(sheetToSearch).Rows.Count

            'If value in the current row (in columnToSearch in sheetToSearch) equals targetValue, copy entire row to LCopyToRow in sheetTarget 
            If Sheets(sheetToSearch).Range(columnToSearch & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = targetValue Then

                'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
                Sheets(sheetToSearch).Rows(LSearchRow).Copy

                'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
                Sheets(sheetTarget).Rows(LCopyToRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                'Move counter to next row
                LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
            End If

            If (LSearchRow >= maxRowToSearch) Then
                Exit For
            End If

        Next LSearchRow

        'Position on cell A3
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("A3").Select

        MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
    End If

    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

I have included some modifications on the original code (on top of the ones you requested); but I have commented everything: take a look at it and let me know if you have any question.

Note that your question refers the third row but your code starts from the second one. I have let it as it was in your code (first row to copy is row number 2).

Comment: Thanks so much for you response.

There is a problem. It is writing in msg box that All matching data has been copied but nothings there (nothing is copied).