# Copy row data based on a search to a separate sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an export of a huge database in Sheet1 (11K rows). The record identifier is in column CQ.

I have a small list (60-100) of record identifiers only in Sheet2, Column A.

I have found the following macro and made some minor modifications to it after 2 days of searching this site. This solution works partially. 
[Find Value on other sheet and copy entire row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500847/find-value-on-other-sheet-and-copy-entire-row)

It will return the first row, but will not keep advancing down the column of data. When I step through, it only seems to continually loop the macro.

Here's the macro as it stands now...

```
Sub SearchForString()

    Dim LCopyToRow As Integer


    On Error GoTo Err_Execute


    'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
    LCopyToRow = 1

    Dim sheetTarget As String: sheetTarget = "sheet2"
    Dim sheetToSearch As String: sheetToSearch = "sheet1"
    Dim targetValue As String: targetValue = Sheets(sheetTarget).Range("A1").Value  'Value in sheet2!A1 to be searched in sheet1
    Dim columnToSearch As String: columnToSearch = "CQ"
    Dim iniRowToSearch As Integer: iniRowToSearch = 1
    Dim LSearchRow As Long 'As far as it is not clear the number of rows you will be considering, better relying on the long type
    Dim maxRowToSearch As Long: maxRowToSearch = 12000 'There are lots of rows, so better setting a max. limit

    If (Not IsEmpty(targetValue)) Then
        For LSearchRow = iniRowToSearch To Sheets(sheetToSearch).Rows.Count

            'If value in the current row (in columnToSearch in sheetToSearch) equals targetValue, copy entire row to LCopyToRow in sheetTarget
            If Sheets(sheetToSearch).Range(columnToSearch & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = targetValue Then

                'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
                Sheets(sheetToSearch).Rows(LSearchRow).Copy

                'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
                Sheets(sheetTarget).Rows(LCopyToRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                'Move counter to next row
                LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
            End If

            If (LSearchRow >= maxRowToSearch) Then
                Exit For
            End If

        Next LSearchRow

        'Position on cell A3
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("A3").Select

        MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
    End If

    Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the given below code to find the last updated Row for both sheet1 and sheet2 as well.

Given below is the code.

```
Sub Testing()
    'for getting the last row udpated, you have to enter the max range reference
    'in our case it is A1048576.  It starts from last and check what is our last
    'row with data in specific to column A.

    'Same can be used for colu
    a = Sheet1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

I would also suggest you this the above code for the given below line in your code.

```
For LSearchRow = iniRowToSearch To Sheets(sheetToSearch).Rows.Count
```

Comment: Where would I add that? I've added it in a couple of places and nothing has changed with the outcome of the macro.

Comment: Will get back to you shortly.

Sandesh :)

Comment: Hi,

Can you please post a sample data.  I tried running your code and it moves to the next row as and when the progress happens.

Sandesh :)

Comment: Can you post the complete macro that is working for you? When I add in what you've suggested, nothing different happens. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you please update a sample data.  Not the exact one, modified one but similar to what need to be achived.

Comment: The one I have is very big file

Comment: How can I upload an excel document to this site? Wouldn't it just be easier to upload your "working" code to see if it works in my document?

Comment: No not a document. for ex...Sheet1 line2 1 25 201, line3 2 60 500

sheet1 line1 1 352 335

Comment: Sheet 1 has data from A1:FS11159 and a unique 8 digit Reference ID of "ZZZZZZZZ" in Column CQ. Sheet2 only has Reference IDs of "ZZZZZZZZ" From A1:A59.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I am not able to help you.  :(

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding why you can't post the code that you say is working as an answer?